# How can I get a reference of the values in a map in C++?

Tags: c++

I want the player of my game to not move if it will collide with other entities.
One solution I've thought would be keeping track of all entities in the game, and when trying to move, check if it will collide with any of those.
The problem is that when looping the vector, I don't get a reference of the entities, but new values, so they have new IDs and I no more can check if the IDs check.

```cpp
 // Actor.cpp
Actor::Actor(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y), m_MovementSpeed(1), m_Alive(true) {
    // ...
    EntityTracker::addEntity(*this);
    this->ID = EntityTracker::entityAmount();
}

void Actor::move(float _x, float _y) {
    for (auto& e : EntityTracker::entities()) {
        if (this->ID != e->ID && this->collides(*e)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    this->x = this->x + _x * m_MovementSpeed;
    this->y = this->y + _y * m_MovementSpeed;
    this->m_Sprite.move(_x * m_MovementSpeed, _y * m_MovementSpeed);
}

// EntityTracker.cpp
uint64_t EntityTracker::s_EntityAmount = 0;
std::map<uint64_t, Actor> EntityTracker::s_Entities {};

void EntityTracker::addEntity(const Actor& actor) {
    EntityTracker::s_Entities.insert(std::pair<uint64_t, Actor>(s_EntityAmount, actor));
    s_EntityAmount++;
}

std::vector<Actor*> EntityTracker::entities() {
    std::vector<Actor*> actors;

    for (auto& it : EntityTracker::s_Entities) {
        std::cout << it.second.ID << std::endl;
        std::cout << it.first << std::endl;
        actors.push_back(&it.second);
    }

    return actors;
}

// EntityTracker.h
class EntityTracker {
public:
    static void addEntity(const Actor& actor);
    static bool removeEntity(uint64_t ID);
    static uint64_t entityAmount();
    static std::vector<Actor*> entities();
private:
    static uint64_t s_EntityAmount;
    static std::map<uint64_t, Actor> s_Entities;
};
```

When I press a key the std::cout's print this:

```
1571901079888 // actor's internal ID from vector
0 // ID from vector
1571901079888
1
1571901079888
0
...
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `std::vector<Actor*>`?

Comment: @S.M. I've tried, but got this error: " In template: 'allocate' declared as a pointer to a reference of type 'Actor &' "

Comment: @S.M. just tried with ``std::vector<Actor*>``. Got the same results. Maybe i'm using it wrong?

Comment: Update your question with the attempt of using pointers.

Comment: Where is the code that populates `s_Entities`? I'm inclined to doubt your analysis of the situation (since you don't know why it does what it does), and we don't have a [mre] so we cannot make our own analysis.

Comment: @JaMiT I edited the post with more code. There could be mistakes, of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return vector of type `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Actor>>` from `EntityTracker::entities()`, an example of such use is below:

```
// Original data
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec.push_back("one");
vec.push_back("two");

// Now its copied as references to rvec
std::vector< std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> rvec;
for(auto& r: vec)
    rvec.push_back(r);
    
// Now output original data using rvec references.
for(auto s: rvec)
    std::cout << s.get() << std::endl;
```

Then inside `Actor::move` you will have access to reference of real Actor instead of its copy. You may also consider keeping `Actor`s as a smart pointers using `std::share_ptr`.

Comment: After a couple of hours of trying things, this finally worked. Thank you!